# Solution for merging data from multiple sql compact databases to a central sql server database using sync framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, merge, microsoft-sync-framework, compact-database

I am currently working on an application for tablets that uses a SQL Server Compact 3.5 database. The need has risen to sync data among tablets. After some research (namely [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb821992.aspx) and [this](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/06/01/database-synchronization-with-the-microsoft-sync-framework.aspx)), my team and I decided to have a central database hosted by SQL Server 2008 R2.

After implementing [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928494(v=sql.110).aspx), there were several drawbacks to this approach:

- I would like to synchronize the entire database, not just a subset of tables. This would require adding primary keys to tables that lack primary keys, let alone adding each table to the sync scope.
- Depending on the sync direction, either the server db (hosted by SQL Server 2008 R2) or the client db (SQL Server Compact 3.5) would have precedence, meaning one db's data may overwrite data made by the other db.

I believe [change tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305322(v=sql.110).aspx) can be useful, and would like to leverage such, if applicable, to find a solution for the following scenario:

The server and three tables are currently synchronized with the same database in the db.

```
ID | NAME
---------
1  | JIM
2  | BOB
3  | JANE
```

The three tablets are taken offline to do their thing.

Tablet 1 adds the following:

```
4 | JOE
```

Tablet 2 adds the following (assuming after tablet 1):

```
4 | BILL
```

Tablet 3 adds the following (assuming after tablet 2):

```
4 | DAVE
```

Then, the tablets reconnect online to sync, in any order. After all is said and done with synchronization, the server db and client dbs should have the following data:

```
ID | NAME
---------
1  | JIM
2  | BOB
3  | JANE
4  | JOE
5  | BILL
6  | DAVE
```

From a DBA standpoint, there is [merge replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx), but I do not have any sysadmin rights on the db server (or administrative rights on a pc itself to give myself sysadmin rights in sql server). Thus, I would like to avoid this route if possible and stick with coding a solution using sync framework (or better).

Am I on the right track after implementing the example above toward eventually finding a solution for my scenario, or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Use guids as keys, not integers

Answer (score 1):

Sync Fx requires a PK (how else can it uniquely identify which row has changed?)

and likewise, you have to explicitly tell it which tables you want to sync.

your scenario will result in to  conflicts though. Sync Fx will no reorder the PK value for you. what it reads from the source is what get's saved on the destination. (how can it tell #4 in client1 is actually #5 on the server?)

Sync Fx or not, using identity values for PK will result to PK value collisions.

Comment: This makes sense. The majority of the tables do not have primary keys, and since I'm not the database guy (and would have to convince him), I'd like to make a convincing case to implement such for this scenario. I also thought timestamps would somehow "merge" things, but I was wrong.

Comment: Are you aware of a solution outside of sync framework that is fitting for my scenario, or would the approach have to change (eg, always be connected to the central database)?